# How to configure Stunnel to connect to a service on HTTP[:3000] through HTTP[:80] and HTTPS[:443]

Tags: http, https, ngrok, stunnel, http-tunneling

I have a `PWA` running on: `127.0.0.1:3000`

With the following `Stunnel` config...

**/etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf**

```
client = no

[default]
accept = 443
cert = /etc/stunnel/example.com.pem
connect = 127.0.0.1:7777

[example.com]
sni = default:*example.com
cert = /etc/stunnel/example.com.pem
connect = 127.0.0.1:3000
```

... I'm able connect to that service by going to (through `HTTPS`):

- https://example.com
- https://www.example.com

But I also wants to connect to that service by going to (through `HTTP`):

- http://example.com
- http://www.example.com

Is there anyway to configure `Stunnel` to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, the stunnel works only on a transport level and doesn't try to analyze packets. But this may be a good addition to it and shouldn't be that difficult. You may propose the change or pay to it's author to implement.

As a workaround you can start a small webserver like `busybox httpd` (already in Ubuntu) or Lighttpd or even just [netcat](https://jameshfisher.com/2018/12/31/how-to-make-a-webserver-with-netcat-nc/) and make a redirect with them. But this would be an additional software to start and configure.
The current most popular solution is to use Nginx upfront as a reverse proxy. This is more complicated but gives more options.